# Change color of an agm-circle on google maps with Angular

Tags: angular

i need to change the color of both circles by pressing three different buttons, called Red, Blue and Green.

I have:

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Imposta qui le tue api key
     AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'GOOGLE_MAPS_API'}),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'map server';

  lat: number = 45.464198;
  lng: number = 9.190545;

  lat2: number = 45.464198;
  lng2: number = 9.190545;
}
```

app.component.html

```
{{title}}
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" >
  </agm-marker>

  <agm-circle [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
      [radius]="5000"
      [fillColor]="'red'">
  </agm-circle>

  <agm-circle [latitude]="lat2" [longitude]="lng2"
      [radius]="7000"
      [fillColor]="'green'">
  </agm-circle>

</agm-map>
```

and

app.component.css

```
agm-map
{
  height: 600px;
}
```

[How to change circles color with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shgwX.png)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't have any error, i only need to know how can i add those buttons and make the color change

Comment: so you want to change color of both circles on click?

Comment: did it worked??

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by making several changes in `.html` file and `.ts` file

First of all we need to make 3 buttons in `.html` file as below

```
<input type="button" value="Red" (click)="onColor('red')">
<input type="button" value="Blue" (click)="onColor('blue')">
<input type="button" value="Green" (click)="onColor('green')">
```

Now you need to create the function in `.ts` file

```
export class AppComponent {
  circleColor: string;
  title = 'map server';

  lat: number = 45.464198;
  lng: number = 9.190545;

  lat2: number = 45.464198;
  lng2: number = 9.190545;

  onColor(color){
    circleColor = color;
  }
}
```

And now at last you need to make small change in your `agm-circle` such as:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" >
  </agm-marker>

  <agm-circle [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
      [radius]="5000"
      [fillColor]="circleColor ">
  </agm-circle>

  <agm-circle [latitude]="lat2" [longitude]="lng2"
      [radius]="7000"
      [fillColor]="circleColor ">
  </agm-circle>

</agm-map>
```

Instead of giving color directly we will pass it from `.ts` fill.